# jquery plugin in backbone + browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript, browserify

The project I'm working on consisted of Backbone and browserify.
I've only worked with jquery and some of javascript.

This is the first project working with Backbone and browserify framworks.
The problem is whenever trying to use jquery plugin something is not working.

Reason why I use jquery plugin is understandable for me.

in package.json

```
"browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "bootstrap": "./src/javascript/vendor/bootstrap.min.js",
    "masonry": "./src/javascript/vendor/masonry.pkgd.min.js",
    "removeClassPrefix": "./src/javascript/vendor/jquery-removeClassPrefix.js",
    "jquery-validate": "./src/javascript/vendor/jquery.validate.min.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim",
      "coffeeify",
      "hbsfy"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$",
    "bootstrap": {
      "exports": "bootstrap",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
      ]
    },
    "masonry": {
      "exports": "masonry",
      "depends": [
        "jquery"
      ]
    },
    "removeClassPrefix": {
      "exports": "removeClassPrefix",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
      ]
    },
    "jquery-validate": {
      "exports": "jquery-validate",
      "depends": [
        "jquery:$"
      ]
    }
  },
```

and actual code written in coffeescript

```
_          = require 'underscore'
Backbone   = require 'backbone'
$ = require 'jquery'
Backbone.$ = $
Backbone.Marionette = require 'backbone.marionette'
ModalModel = require '../models/modalModel'
jquery-validate = require 'jquery-validate'

module.exports = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend
```

After building codes, an error occurred on the first line of the code above.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jquery is not defined
```

without code below everything works fine.

```
jquery-validate = require 'jquery-validate'
```

That means there is something quite not working in the jquery plugin(jquery-validate)
jquery-validate is expending jquery function I guess.

Is there any way I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use dashes in a valid JavaScript variable identifier, so try changing `jquery-validate = require 'jquery-validate'` to `jquery_validate = require 'jquery-validate'`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much, adamyonk.
I guess I'm starting to get used to Javascript.

Comment: Glad to help! It's definitely a challenging one, but a very useful tool. Stay with it!